# Slide in list items one after the other in CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I want the list items to slide in one after the other. This procedure in CSS seems a bit complex. Is there an easier way to do this?

```
#nav ul.is-visible{visibility:visible;opacity:1;-webkit-transform:scale(1);-ms-transform:scale(1);transform:scale(1);-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.3s,visibility 0 0;transition:transform 0.3s,visibility 0 0}
    #nav ul.is-visible li:nth-child(1){-webkit-animation:slide-in .2s;animation:slide-in .2s}
    #nav ul.is-visible li:nth-child(2){-webkit-animation:slide-in .3s;animation:slide-in .3s}
    #nav ul.is-visible li:nth-child(3){-webkit-animation:slide-in .4s;animation:slide-in .4s}
    #nav ul.is-visible li:nth-child(4){-webkit-animation:slide-in .5s;animation:slide-in .5s}
    #nav ul.is-visible li:nth-child(5){-webkit-animation:slide-in .6s;animation:slide-in .6s}
    #nav ul.is-visible li:nth-child(6){-webkit-animation:slide-in .7s;animation:slide-in .7s}
    #nav ul.is-visible li:nth-child(7){-webkit-animation:slide-in .8s;animation:slide-in .8s}
    #nav ul.is-visible li:nth-child(8){-webkit-animation:slide-in .9s;animation:slide-in .9s}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Mark I think following code will help you for list items,

```
<style>
   ul li
   { display:inline; }

  .slider
  { width:100%; overflow:hidden; }

  ul { animation: slide-left 20s; }

  @keyframes slide-left {
    from {
     margin-left: 100%; width: 300%; 
    }

   to {
     margin-left: 0%; width: 100%;
    }
   }
 </style>

 <body>

    <div class="slider"> 
       <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
          <li> List Item 1 </li>
          <li> List Item 2 </li>
          <li> List Item 3 </li>
          <li> List Item 4 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

 </body>
```